# Notify a variable Android

Tags: android, variables, notifications, calculator

Please excuse me if I am being a noob, but I just completed an Android programming tutorial, and tried making my own app, but don't know how to do something (which is ok, right?). So yeah, I made a simple calculator app, and tried to have it notify the user the result, so I made an int called result which is the value of two editTexts added together. I tried making a notification with the contentText being the result int, but I don't reallyknow how to do that as it will only take a string... Help. If you need the code the just say so.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the int to a String using Strings valueOf method:

```
String string = String.valueOf(result);
```

Or you could use String format method if you wish to have text too:

```
int result = 0;
String.format("Result: %d", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting int to String like this

```
String resultString = String.valueOf(resultInt);
```